# Cannot embed a Javascript App on a Vaadin Website

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin

I am currently expanding this (https://github.com/frankskol/AdaptiveTesting2/tree/master) Adaptive Testing site that uses Vaadin 7 to include a mode with questions from Geogebra. The relevant classes here are DefaultView and GeogebraTestView. The problem is that i cannot get the app to run.
According to the Geogebra wiki (https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Apps_Embedding), there are four steps for App Embedding.

1) Add information to meta in head section

2) Include the javascript library deployggb.js

3) Create an element for the GeoGebra app on your page

4) Configure and insert the app

My problem is on step 4, as i cannot get the Javascript to be executed.

Steps 1 and 2 have already been done in defaultView in the method `servletInitialized()`. Both the library and the meta configurations can be seen at the head.
For step 3 I created a new Label with the `div` and added it. Can also be seen in the Code HTML, so that should be working.
For step 4 I created a String with the script and tried to execute it with `Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(script.toString());` as seen here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/791748/how-to-add-javascript-file-and-in-script-tags
However, the app still does not appear on the page.

`JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("alert('Hello')");` also does not work, and the other solution, `getApplication().getMainWindow().executeJavaScript(script.toString());` does not seem to work here, as the program doesn't recognize either `getApplication` or `getMainWindow()`.

```
Label ggbElement = new Label("<div id=\"ggb-element\"></div>",ContentMode.HTML);
addComponent(ggbElement);

StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.append("var ggbApp = new GGBApplet({\"appName\": \"graphing\", \"width\": 800, \"height\": 600, \"showToolBar\": true, \"showAlgebraInput\": true, \"showMenuBar\": true }, true);")
            .append("  window.addEventListener(\"load\", function() { ggbApp.inject('ggb-element');\n" +
                        "    });");
//execute Javascript
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(script.toString());
//or
//Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(script.toString());
```

The expected result would be the Geogebra App appearing on the page, as seen in one of the Live examples at the Geogebra Wiki, but the actual result is just the blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are calling the JS to early (the page is not loaded yet, no components are attached).
I am not sure about the Geogebra, but try to execute your JavaScript on `attachListener` of the Label like this:

```
Label lb=new Label();
lb.addAttachListener(e->{
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("YOUR SCRIPT");
});
```

At least, the general JS commands  like `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("alert('Hello')");` should work from there.